# SDL2 does not generate KEYDOWN and KEYUP events for accent key

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I want to use the keys as a game control not to write text.

I have tried `SDL_StopTextInput();` but this only disables the `SDL_TEXTINPUT` event and does not create `SDL_KEYDOWN` and `SDL_KEYUP` events

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#define ANCHO 800
#define ALTO 600

int main (int n, char **argumentos)
{
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_X11_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR, "0");//No suspende el compositor de ventana (No funciona en devuan mate)
    //error: ‘SDL_HINT_VIDEO_X11_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR’ was not declared in this scope (devuan mate)
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_MINIMIZE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS, "0");
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_IME_INTERNAL_EDITING, "1");
    SDL_Window *ventana = SDL_CreateWindow("Ejemplo", 0, 0, ANCHO, ALTO, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_GLContext contexto = SDL_GL_CreateContext(ventana);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);//Limita a 60 fps

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glEnable (GL_CULL_FACE);
    glViewport(0, 0, ANCHO, ALTO);
    glClearColor(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1.0);
    //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    SDL_StopTextInput();
    bool terminar = false;
    while (!terminar)
    {
        SDL_Event evento;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evento))
        {
            if(evento.type == SDL_TEXTEDITING)
                std::cout << "SDL_TEXTEDITING" << "\n";
            else if(evento.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
                std::cout << "SDL_TEXTINPUT" << "\n";
            else if(evento.type == SDL_KEYMAPCHANGED)
                std::cout << "SDL_KEYMAPCHANGED" << "\n";
            else if(evento.type == SDL_SYSWMEVENT)
                std::cout << "SDL_SYSWMEVENT" << "\n";
            else if(evento.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                std::cout << "SDL_KEYDOWN" << "\n";
            else if(evento.type == SDL_KEYUP)
                std::cout << "SDL_KEYUP" << "\n";
            else if (evento.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT)
            {
                if (evento.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE)
                    terminar = true;
            }
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(ventana);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Operating system: Gentoo 64bits

Keyboard: Spanish/Spanish

Neither of the 2 accents works: `´` and `` ` ``

Comment: To clarify, by accent key you mean what is also known as "dead keys" or "compose key", right?

Comment: May be helpful https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/how-can-i-handle-different-keyboard-layouts

Comment: Tell us the operating system and keyboard layout in use too.

Comment: Also since this sounds so exactly like a problem with SDL text input make sure your code is not calling it from another thread or something.

Comment: Add a code, it worked before but in ubuntu, the grave accent produced the following key.keysym.sym: 1073741824

Comment: @ZanLynx Yes, but I want to use as a normal keys

Comment: Thanks for the program. I just tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 after adding a Spanish keyboard input and it seems to work for me. I get KEYDOWN events for all the keys I press.

Comment: Ah, test details: I used 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome gnome-shell in Wayland mode. I went to Settings: Region & Language: Input Sources and added a Spanish keyboard layout. I can type accented characters like ẻ by using Right-Alt + j, e for example.

Comment: @ZanLynx It also worked for me in ubuntu, so I think it must be a default sdl2 configuration, some "SDL_Hint", but I haven't found anything.

Comment: what is the advantage of scancode?

Comment: Ignore scancode comment, I was confused. :-)

Comment: Well actually, try scancode. I was thinking that scancode is never translated by input method, it is simply the raw keyboard output code.

Comment: I have tried glut, and it works perfectly, so it must be a matter of sdl2